# Determine number of logged in users with the same gmail, flutter cloudfirestore

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following scenario: 
The user logs in with user@gmail.com using google sign in button inside my application.
A value in the database called number is increased by one to indicate the number of users for this current account.
The user logs out, the value of number decreases indicating the number of current users for the account.
Now the following may happen:

- Issue 1: The user may delete the application without logging out showing an extra device number although it is not true.
- Issue 2: The user may clear the data of the application without logging out which also indicates an additional number of used devices which is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WidgetsBindingObserver and override the didChangeAppLifecycleState method.
For more details [check this link.](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html)

Comment: Ok I will check and see.

Comment: do you have any tutorials on such a topic

Comment: here is a good tutorial i found about it https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=3&v=au5mI--ql9A

Comment: Ok thanks alot, I will watch it and see if things go well .

Comment: Well this video solves 90% of the problem, there is now a new issue that will appear if I use the logic presented in the video.                          Isue: The application is in paused state and I now tried to set login to false in my databse, wihch solves the problem and then if the user returns I set it to true but what if the user had no internet connection when the application became paused then deleted it. Here the database will not be persisted. What to do